# Bundled Gems won't load libxml using the require parameter in rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm currently moving a site onto bundler to make the gem requirements easier to manage, aid in deployment, and speed up developer setup.  I'm running into one gem I can't seem to remove from the environment.rb file.

In environment.rb

`config.gem 'libxml-ruby', :version => '1.1.4', :lib => 'libxml'`

In Gemfile

```
gem 'libxml-ruby', '1.1.4', :require => 'libxml'
```

If I leave the reference in the environment.rb file everything works.  I'd like to not have to leave that line though.

Note: the error I get if I don't leave it in environment.rb is

```
activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:131:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant BaseSaxParser::XML (NameError)
```

Looking through the stack trace, it seems like a plugin "activemq_xml_parser.rb" is looking for it before it's loaded.  Any thoughts on that?

Help is greatly appreciated!

note: I know specifying exact versions in the Gemfile isn't the best idea.  My idea is to get it working, then tweak to clean things up.